# Border Radius is working only in IE but not in other browsers

Tags: css

Below is the the CSS class am using.It's working fine in IE with border-radius and padding .But same is not working in Mozilla and other browsers.Stuck from two days can any one help me out?

```
.node-tl-img-with-circle {
        /* become base of .circle::after */
       /* position: relative;*/
         -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* width and height are depend on the icon size */
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;


        /* color of circle */
        /*background-color: #F4B272;*/

        /* make div circle */

        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;

      padding:8px;

       /*margin: 5px;*/

        /* The outermost stroke is as same as background color */
        /*border: 4px solid #FFF;*


        /*box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #F4B272; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #F4B272; 
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #F4B272; */
    }
```

Comment: This must work. Can you make a full [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: IE version is 11 , mozilla version is 45 and chrome version is 51.I dint get u vucko full fiddle in the sense?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: Post your full HTML and CSS in the fiddle, save it and then edit your OP with the link to the fiddle.

Comment: Have you tried creating it in for example jsfiddle and see if it works for you? https://jsfiddle.net/zs49j07t/

Answer (score 1):

First you could provide a good sample case next time in codepen fiddle or something.

Anyway border-radious should work for all browsers from:

- +IE 9
- +Firefox 4
- +Chrome 5
- +Safari 7
- +Opera 11.5

[see in caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

HTML

```
<div class="sample"></div>
```

CSS

```
.sample {
  box-sizing    : border-box;
  width         : 40px;
  height        : 40px;
  padding       :  8px;
  border        :  4px solid red;
  border-radius : 50%;
}
```

This is working, so we cannot help you more if you don't provide us a better sample, maybe other chunk of code is crashing this part.

Comment: thank u leon ...but do we need to add this in case of mozilla and chrome?    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;

Comment: If you go to the CANIUSE link that i posted you, you could see all the browsers that support that css property. Click on the SEE ALL button, 
Then you would see small yellow div with the prefixes within the version.
You only need it in case you want to support older browsers.

I don't worry about prefixes because i use in my workflow autoprefixer 
(is available for gulp, grunt or webpack) and is commonly used to setup autoprefix base on the %browserUsage, in my case just higher than >4%

So if for example just 3% of the world use Firefox 4, in my case i avoid it.
Hope this help